# Python Pandas Reshape Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a collection of measurements under various parameters stored as a list of dicts and converted to a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{"Device": "A", "temperature": 0, "Load": 1, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.1, "Measurement2": 0.9},
 {"Device": "A", "temperature": 0, "Load": 2, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.5, "Measurement2": 1.3},
 {"Device": "A", "temperature": 40, "Load": 1, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.2, "Measurement2": 1},
 {"Device": "A", "temperature": 40, "Load": 2, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.6, "Measurement2": 1.4},
 {"Device": "B", "temperature": 0, "Load": 1, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.3, "Measurement2": 1.1},
 {"Device": "B", "temperature": 0, "Load": 2, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.7, "Measurement2": 1.5},
 {"Device": "B", "temperature": 40, "Load": 1, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.4, "Measurement2": 1.2},
 {"Device": "B", "temperature": 40, "Load": 2, "Voltage": 5,  "Measurement1": 0.8, "Measurement2": 1.6}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Device', 'temperature', 'Load', 'Voltage', 'Measurement1', 'Measurement2'])
df
```

[Initial data Jupyter output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyBHB.png)

This is a screenshot of the 
[desired structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDCvm.png).

I have tried a pivot table, as the idea is quite similar, having columns/index/values as parameters, as well as separate transpose/reindexing/setting columns but I could not get the combination.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Can you add output with your input data?

Comment: I have updated the initial post with revised data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, `set_index`, `T`, and `stack`:

```
df.set_index(['Load','Voltage','Device','temperature']).T.stack([0,1])
```

Output:

```
Device                       A         B     
temperature                 0    40   0    40
             Load Voltage                    
Measurement1 1    5        0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
             2    5        0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8
Measurement2 1    5        0.9  1.0  1.1  1.2
             2    5        1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6
```

And, you don't want those column index names add `rename_axis`:

```
(df.set_index(['Load','Voltage','Device','temperature']).T.stack([0,1])
        .rename_axis([None,None],1))
```

Output:

```
                             A         B     
                            0    40   0    40
             Load Voltage                    
Measurement1 1    5        0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
             2    5        0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8
Measurement2 1    5        0.9  1.0  1.1  1.2
             2    5        1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6
```